# How to centre all QGIS composers on the main map canvas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-modeler

I have a template project that will be used for many future sites and I want to automatically centre **all** the composer layout maps to the same centre as the main canvas. Ideally this would be done as part of a processing model.
I have looked at using an expression for the layout maps extents but I can't see a canvas property to work with.
I could use a single feature in an atlas setup but that adds complications I don't really want.

Comment: When should this centering happen? Everytime you move the canvas? Once you open a layout?

Comment: before I export the maps, which I would also like to do using the graphical modeller

Comment: For what I know there is no solution to get the extend of the current view of the QGIS canva.
What you could do would be to define a project variable that will be used by your layout and that you could modify. would it suit your needs @Sethinacan ?

Comment: @CorentinLemaitre That seems like the closest option, it works and stops the scales from changing

Answer (score 2):

### Principles

Each map in each layout have in property scale extents and the possibility to set the extent based on atlas.

[image]

What you want to do is not atlas but is data driven extent.

### Step by step

1. Copy the extent from your actual canvas : [image]
2. Create the variable to store your extent. Click on the `+` and name the variable `canvas_extent` fill it with what you have copied before.

[image]

3. Set the extent `X min` based on data the expression should be : `array_get(string_to_array(replace (@canvas_extent, array(',',' : '), array (',',','))),0)`.

[image]

4. For Y min it will be `array_get(string_to_array(replace (@canvas_extent, array(',',' : '), array (',',','))),1)`, for X max it will be `array_get(string_to_array(replace (@canvas_extent, array(',',' : '), array (',',','))),2)` and for Y max it will be `array_get(string_to_array(replace (@canvas_extent, array(',',' : '), array (',',','))),3)`

Repeat the steps for each layout you have.

When you change your variable canvas_extent value it will update the layout extent.

Comment: What I have done is similar but I added a variable for the centre then used expressions to calculate the extents which allows maps at different scales

Comment: Sadly layouts don't update automatically

Answer (score 0):

You could drop this into the Python Console and this should just work:

```
extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layouts = projectLayoutManager.layouts()
for layout in layouts:
    for item in layout.items():
        if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemMap):
            scale = item.scale()
            size = item.sizeWithUnits()
            item.setExtent(extent)
            item.setScale(scale)
            item.attemptResize(size)
            item.refresh()
```

Comment: its a good answer but in my case I have maps at different scales so need to work with a centre

Comment: OK, edited. Almost the same answer as before, but you get the scale before you change the extent and set the scale back afterward.

Comment: ...and fixed the layout item size change that occurs. I'm sure there has to be a more simple way to do this, but the code above works.